# SVG gradient animation not working in iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, svg

**My animated gradient is not rendering properly in iOS Safari when referenced from any `SVG` element other than the one in which it is defined.**

Everything works as expected in Chrome and Firefox on my laptop. In iOS Safari the second animation appears frozen. Oddly enough when I rotate the display to toggle between portrait and landscape orientation the animation will appear to jump and freeze in a new position.

Is this a bug in iOS Safari or am I doing something wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/yFthP/258/

```css
svg {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 128 128" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="shimmer" cx="0" cy="1" r="2">
      <stop offset="-0.5" stop-color="MediumSlateBlue">
        <animate attributeName="offset" from="-0.5" to="1" dur="2500ms" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="-0.25" stop-color="DeepSkyBlue">
        <animate attributeName="offset" from="-0.25" to="1.25" dur="2500ms" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="MediumSlateBlue">
        <animate attributeName="offset" from="0" to="1.5" dur="2500ms" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
    </radialGradient> 
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#shimmer)"></rect>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 128 128" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#shimmer)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: On desktop Safari, **moving the mouse in and out of the iframe**, **typing** and **minimizing/switching the window** triggers the animation to jump to another frame. It is moving in the speed of my typing right now. So strange.

Comment: @the4kman Thanks for that info! I don't have a Mac so I couldn't test on desktop Safari, just my iPhone. Hopefully that will make it easier for someone to spot what is going on.